# How to Exclude nested fields from documents using Aggregation project operation via java springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have been working java spring boot project and using MongoDB version 4.2.8 as a database. I wanted to exclude nested fields from the response in the aggregation query, but it's not working with `Exclude()` option of the `Aggregation.project()`.

While the same thing works if I choose `Include()`.

```
 Aggregation aggr = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                        Aggregation.match(orCriteria.orOperator(orExpression.toArray(new Criteria[orExpression.size()]))),
                        Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("ods_ref_domain").in(domain)),
                        Aggregation.group(Fields.fields().and("ods_value_set_name").and("value_set_type_id")
                                .and("source_system")).push("$$ROOT").as("data"),
                        new AggregationOperation() {
                            @Override
                            public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aoc) {
                                return new Document("$addFields", new Document("_id.refData", "$data"));
                            }
                        }, Aggregation.project().and("_id").as("refObject").andExclude("_id")
                        
                        ,Aggregation.unwind("refObject.refData")
                        ,Aggregation.project().andExclude("refObject.refData._id")
                ).withOptions(newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(true).build());
```